# void sum(a,b) Невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из " comp" в "a"

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

void sum(struct a, struct b);
void mult(struct a, struct b);
void divis(struct a, struct b);

using namespace std;

struct comp {
    float Re;
    float Im;
};

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    comp a;
    comp b;

    cout << "\t\tПервое комплексное число\n";
    cout << "Введите действительную часть: ";
    cin >> a.Re; cout << endl;

    cout << "Введите мнимую часть: ";
    cin >> a.Im; cout << endl;

    if (a.Im > 0) {
        cout << "\tZ = " << a.Re << " + " << a.Im << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "\tZ = " << a.Re << " - " << abs(a.Im) << "i" << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << "\t\tВторое комплексное число\n";

    cout << "Введите действительную часть: ";
    cin >> b.Re; cout << endl;

    cout << "Введите мнимую часть: ";
    cin >> b.Im; cout << endl;

    if (b.Im > 0) {
        cout << "\tZ = " << b.Re << " + " << b.Im << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "\tZ = " << b.Re << " - " << abs(b.Im) << "i" << endl;
    }

    cout << ("Введите знак действия который хотите совершить -, +, *, /");
    char znak;
    cin >> znak;
    if (znak == '-' || znak == '+')
        cout << "Ответ: "; sum(a, b);    
    if (znak == '/')
        cout << "Ответ: "; divis(a, b);
    if (znak == '*')
        cout << "Ответ: "; mult(a, b);
}


void sum(comp a,comp b) {
    float RE = a.Re + b.Re;
    float IM = a.Im + b.Im;
    cout << "Ответ: ";
    if (IM < 0) {
        cout << RE << " - " << abs(IM) << "i\n";
    }
    else
        cout << RE << " + " << IM << "i\n";
}

void mult(comp a, comp b) {
    float RE = a.Re * b.Re - a.Im*b.Im;
    float IM = a.Re * b.Im + b.Re * a.Im;
    if (IM < 0)
        cout << RE << " - " << abs(IM) << "i\n";
    else
        cout << RE << " + " << IM << "i\n";
}

void divis(comp a, comp b) {
    float RE = (a.Re * b.Re + a.Im * b.Im) / (a.Im * a.Im + a.Re * a.Re);
    float IM = (a.Re * b.Im - b.Re * a.Im) / (a.Im * a.Im + a.Re * a.Re);
    if (IM < 0)
        cout << RE << " - " << abs(IM) << "i\n";
    else
        cout << RE << " + " << IM << "i\n";
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста если вам помог один из ответов приведенных ниже, отметьте его как "Правильный ответ", нажав на галочку слева от ответа :)

Answer (score 2):

```
void sum(struct a, struct b);
```

Означает, что функция принимает 2 аргумента. Первый аргумент типа `a`, второй аргумент типа `b`, а вы хотите передавать в эту функция структуру `comp`.

В прототипе функции можно писать только тип аргумента, то есть так:

```
void sum(comp, comp);
```

Можно писать названия аргументов, но это не обязательно:

```
void sum(comp a, comp b);
```

Ну или же так:

```
void sum(struct comp a, struct comp b);
```

Но это больше стиль `си`. (Я лично ни разу не видел такое в коде на `c++`)

Так же ваши функции не знают о структуре `comp`. Для этого вы можете или структуру `comp` определить выше всех прототипов функций, которые её используют. Или так же написать прототип для структуры, например после `unclude`ов, но главное перед функциями использующие эту структуру:

```
struct comp;
```

Comment: 98 вижуал не компилил мой код без фортелей с struct и typedef.

Comment: что? Все что понял, так это то, что у вас что-то не компилируется.

Comment: В давние времена у меня была вижуал 98 и просто так определение структур она не ела. Вот совсем.

Comment: Вряд ли автор использует 98 версию визуалки. Хотя думаю полезно знать с какой версии это добавили, если знаете можете написать.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct comp
{
    float Re;
    float Im;
};

void sum(comp a, comp b);
void mult(comp a, comp b);
void divis(comp a, comp b);
```